# Is there a way to create user-configurable Custom Retention Formulas, possibly through Custom Properties?

Tags: feature

I am wanting to create a "user" - configurable Custom Retention Formula?
Something like a simple version of the rules that Excel and other applications have which displays something like:

Field:________________  Equals:__________________

Is it possible to use something like Custom Properties added to webparts ([refer this msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28office.11%29.aspx)) with Custom Retention Policies?

I am looking for something fairly simple or it won't really be worth the development time for this particular project.

[Edit]

I found [this example](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2011/03/01/how-to-pass-parametersconfig-data-into-custom-expiration-formula/), but it looks like you have to do it when adding the Formula to a content type or list through code, which is not exactly "user"-configurable.  I am looking for some way to set this up so it can be set through the UI that allows you to add custom retention formulas, if possible.